# Node-RED, IOT Foundation Out Node Not Sending Commands

Tags: mqtt, ibm-cloud, iot, node-red

I have a Node-RED application that is bound to an IOT Foundation (iotf) service. I can receive events from devices and handle them appropriately.

However, I am now interested in sending commands back to my devices and am having some problems. Nothing is showing up at the device, but by creating an IOTF in node, I can confirm that the command is passing through iotf.

I can definitely get commands to pass through iotf using pure python, as the follow code works well:

**Client code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ibmiotf.device
from time import sleep

options = {
  "org": "cgmncc",
  "type": "table",
  "id": "b827eb764b7a",
  "auth-method": "token",
  "auth-token": "redacted"
}

def myCommandCallback(cmd):
  print('inside command callback')
  print cmd

def main():
  client = ibmiotf.device.Client(options)
  client.connect()
  client.commandCallback = myCommandCallback
  while True:
    sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

**Application code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import ibmiotf.application

options = {
  "org": "redacted",
  "id": "python app",
  "auth-method": "apikey",
  "auth-key": "redacted",
  "auth-token": "redacted"
}

try:
  client = ibmiotf.application.Client(options)
  client.connect()
  client.publishCommand('table', 'b827eb764b7a', 'test')
  client.disconnect()
except ibmiotf.ConnectionException as e:
  print e
```

Whenever I run the application code, I see the following output:

```
root@raspberrypi ~ # ./app.py 
inside command callback
<ibmiotf.device.Command instance at 0x14e8490>
```

I have a Node-RED iotf output node configured as shown below, but when I trigger the flow, the command callback function doesn't trigger!

[image]
[image]

I'm thinking there maybe something wrong either with trying to use a timestamp trigger to fire the command, or with the way I've configured the output node itself -- any suggestions or advice would be appreciated!

Comment: Your device type "table" seems a bit odd. Is that how you registered your device?   Please provide your org so I can check your registered devices.

Comment: Thanks @ValerieLampkin
You can take a look, my org is cgmncc.
I can definitely send commands to the device using a python application registered to the same organization, but whenever I try to do the same from Node-RED, nothing is showing up on the device. I'm not sure if the commands are even making it to the IOT foundation (historian doesn't appear to have an API for seeing command messages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple test to check if the commands are reaching IBM IoT Foundation is - developing another flow having an IoT App In node which subscribes to the commands. I am attaching the Node-RED flow for the same here

```html
[
{
    "id": "40560f8b.30693",
    "type": "ibmiot in",
    "authentication": "boundService",
    "apiKey": "",
    "inputType": "cmd",
    "deviceId": "b827eb764b7a",
    "applicationId": "",
    "deviceType": "table",
    "eventType": "",
    "commandType": "test",
    "format": "string",
    "name": "IBM IoT App In",
    "service": "registered",
    "allDevices": false,
    "allApplications": "",
    "allDeviceTypes": false,
    "allEvents": "",
    "allCommands": false,
    "allFormats": false,
    "x": 268,
    "y": 171,
    "z": "6bd610b9.7b40a",
    "wires": [
        [
            "2f9b9c00.8b7ba4"
        ]
    ]
},
{
    "id": "2f9b9c00.8b7ba4",
    "type": "debug",
    "name": "",
    "active": true,
    "console": "false",
    "complete": "false",
    "x": 493,
    "y": 195,
    "z": "6bd610b9.7b40a",
    "wires": []
}
]
```

It would appear this way in the workspace.
[image]

After you have added this flow, you can test the device command publishing from the same workspace.
Can you please try this? Since you would now have 2 debug nodes, you should be able to see the same timetamp output twice. I have tried the same flow, with the same details (except the organization) and it works fine.

Thanks and Regards
Amit M Mangalvedkar

Comment: Hi @amit-mangalvedkar thanks for the response.
I did try as you suggest and do see the timestamp twice in the output. So this tells me that the command is indeed making it through the IOT Foundation. I am now going to boot up my Raspberry Pi and reconnect it to the IOT Foundation to see if it'll receive the command as well.

Comment: I updated the original question with the code that I'm running on the device, it's still not receiving any commands as far as I can tell!

Comment: In the device code that you had pasted earlier, I am unable see any entry for the command type getting set to "test". Could you please post the entire client code (while just masking the auth token)?

Comment: Hi Amit, that's the entire device code. I don't see any way to set the command type from the documentation.
https://docs.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com/libraries/python_cli_for_devices.html#handling-commands

Please advise!

Comment: I completely missed this comment and although more than 4 months have passed, I would like to know if this problem still persists.

Comment: Honestly it was so long ago I cannot recall what it was that got me over the hurdle, but I did indeed get the thing to work! I'm going to mark your answer as correct, as it did lead me to the solution...... whatever it was <blush/>